# Atualizar coluna com ordenação de itens

Tags: sql, oracle

Olá,

Em uma determinada tabela de relacionamento eu possuo uma coluna que guarda a ordenação, porém devido a um problema na aplicação essa coluna foi populado dados errados, conforme o exemplo

```
|user_log
-------------------------------------------
|user_id    |log_id |seq_num| created_date |
-------------------------------------------
|175300     |368501 |0      |
|175300     |368502 |0      |
|175300     |368503 |0      |
|175336     |368504 |0      |
|175389     |368505 |0      |
|175389     |368506 |0      |
```

Eu preciso criar um script sql, que corrija essa ordenação, populando a coluna de seq_num com a ordem de criação, determinada pela coluna created_date. Exemplo:

```
-------------------------------------------
|user_id    |log_id |seq_num| created_date |
-------------------------------------------
|175300     |368501 |0      |
|175300     |368502 |1      |
|175300     |368503 |2      |
```

Alguém tem uma ideia de como montar esse script sql?
OBS: o banco de dados é Oracle.

Comment: o seu campo created_date  não tem valor? é datetime?

Comment: a coluna created_date sempre é preenchida com a data do insert, não coloquei no exemplo, desculpa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá,

Para isto é necessário rodar o seguinte sql:

`MERGE INTO user_log t2 using (select log_id, rownum n from user_log order by created_date) t1 on (t1.log_id = t2.log_id) 
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE set t2.seq_num = t1.n`

Alterando o uso do campo log_id pela primary key.

**Tá, mas o que isso faz?**

primeiro faz o sub-select:

```
select log_id, rownum n from user_log order by created_date
```

seleciona a ID e o número da linha correspondente a tabela ordenada pela data, a tabela fica mais ou menos assim:

`___________________
| log_id | rownum |
|--------|--------|
| 5001   | 0      |
| 5003   | 1      |
| 5002   | 2      |
| 5004   | 3      |
-------------------`

Depois a tabela é varrida a procura de uma condição que satisfaça a condição do merge:

```
on (t1.log_id = t2.log_id)
```

se achou algum registro faz um update:

```
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE set t2.seq_num = t1.n
```

Espero ter esclarecido suas dúvidas.

**#EDIT**

Para o caso específico de o seq_num ter que começar do 0 *para cada* usuário deve-se usar o seguinte SQL:

`merge into user_log t2 using (
   select user_id, log_id, ROW_NUMBER()
   over (partition by user_id order by created_date) as seq_num
   from user_log
) t1 on (t1.log_id = t2.log_id and t1.user_id = t2.user_id) 
when matched then update set t2.seq_num = (t1.seq_num -1)`

Para maiores informações do comando utilizado acesse o seguinte link:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, porém o MERGE tem que agrupar por user_id, a sequencia é por usuario.

Comment: Neste cado deverá ser alterado o subselect, para retornar a rownum de acordo